# Stitch together images taken at similar times from different satellites

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, time-series, spatial-filter

I assume this is a very common problem, but I don't know where to start.

Given two Google Earth Engine image collections (both containing a timeseries of images and multiple scenes), how can I construct a "mosaic" with bands from both collections for matching times?

For example, to create a dataset for January 5 covering my area of interest, I may need to stitch together:

- Landsat scene "x" taken at 10:00pm on Jan 5 with Sentinel scene "a" taken at 3:00am on Jan 6
- Landsat scene "y" taken at 10:07pm on Jan 5 with Sentinel scene "b" taken at 3:15am on Jan 6
- Landsat scene "z" taken at 10:20pm on Jan 5 with Sentinel scene "c" taken at 3:05am on Jan 6
  etc.

In other words, I need to take multiple scenes from the first collection (to cover the area of interest), and then find corresponding scenes from the second collection that: (i) overlap the first set (spatially), and (ii) which were taken at similar times.

I can use a filtering method (ee.Join.saveBest) to find images that correspond in time, but this ignores the spatial aspect.

I am looking for a way to do this using Google Earth Engine.

Comment: Does this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206932/accessing-joined-image-using-ee-join-savefirst-in-google-earth-engine?rq=1 help?